# Classification Of Homology Theories

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose we have a Homology theory $\tilde{H}$ which satisfies the dimension axiom and there exists $k>0$ such that for each $0\leq i \leq k$, we have a canonical isomorphism between $\tilde{H}_k$ and $k$-th singular homology. In general, is $\tilde{H}$ isomorohic to singular homology?

Answer (score 3):

No, for any $k$ counter examples exist. For example, the direct sum of two homology theories is a homology theory because the direct sum of two long exact sequence is a long exact sequence. As well the shift of any homology theory is a homology theory. Then a counterexample is given by direct summing singular homology with its shift by k.

Comment: Suppose the homology theory satisfies the dimension axiom, do you know any counter example in this case?

Comment: If you satisfy the dimension axiom, then you are forced to be homology with coefficients. Then if $k>0$ we have that first homologous agree, but the first homology of a circle is the coefficient group. So if the first homologies agree it implies the ordinary homology is the same.